# Performance losses due to whole disk encryption? PGP vs LUKS vs other?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, disk-encryption, pgp, luks

How is performance impacted by whole disk encryption systems such as PGP or LUKS?

How do PGP and LUKS compare in performance?

Im working on Ubuntu 10.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whole disk encryption doesn't put more load on the hard drive.  The extra load comes from encrypting/decrypting the data which is done by the CPU.

In my experience, *not using either of the above products,* most operations didn't have a significant end user perceived performance penalty but did incur a bit more CPU load (~ %10) than the same operations without encryption.

Comment: which encryption software have you used? any specific issues? Im contemplating changing over my multi boot laptop over to fully encrypted since I do alot of traveling

Comment: It was about 5 years ago so I don't recall the application's name.  It was full disk encryption on the company provided laptop.  I recall the initial install taking about 2 days to encrypt the entire drive in the background.  After that the laptop ran just about is it did before the install with a slightly higher CPU load.